# Postfix config with a single catch-all user

Tags: postfix, imap

Here is a very simple question that I wasn't able to find an easy answer for being entirely new to postfix:

I want all mail coming in from SMTP (or through local delivery for that matter) to drop in a single (special purpose) user's Maildir, for later pick-up by a web app through IMAP (Dovecot).

I already have it configured to find the destination through

```
local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd.byname
```

and created a user for that single purpose, but I'd rather have Postfix not even try to look up the user named in the incoming mail, just take the one user I specify in the config.

What's the simplest and most secure way to do this?

Addendum: [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-postfix-catch-all-email-accounts/) shows how to use virtual_alias_map, but I don't want virtual domains, I want all emails coming in, regardless of the (multiple) domains I've set up to go into the catch-all.

Comment: try something like "local_recipient_maps = static:yourCatchAll"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the very bottom of this page for information on the luser_relay variable:

http://www.postfix.org/rewrite.html

Perhaps that will get you the functionality you desire.

Comment: Thanks, that did it, along with Bill Weiss's "static" local_recipient_map

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the `always_bcc` option. All Mail which gets in or out will be delivered to defined mailbox/user/whatever.

If you only want incoming Mails use

```
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc
```

or for outgoing mail

```
sender_bcc_maps =  hash:/etc/postfix/sender_bcc
```

In the maps you can define * to match all domains, or filter domain specific with

(atsign)foobar.com    mailbox

If you have your mapfile, build it with postmap hash:/etc/postfix/yourhashmap